# Basic HTTP Authentication: API request: get data

Tags: php, api, curl, basic-authentication

I'm pretty new to Basic HTTP Authentication (PHP) and would like to know how I can authenticate myself on the api of another website. I have a username and password to get access to the external api. Username is in $this->id, password is in $this->key.

This is the api url to get the data I want:
http://api.medipim.be/v2/web/product/print/0011890?language=nl&user_id='.$this->id.'&validation='.$this->key

How do I authenticate myself? Any options via curl?

Answer (score 1):

Otto's answer is generally the right way to do authentication for the medipim api using php & curl. However, the api call in question does not require http authentication; the request is authenticated using a token based on your credentials. This way the url can be passed to a (web)client without exposing your api key. We've recently updated the documentation for this call, so you might want to have another look.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, CURL can set the user and pass for you:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
```

Replace `$username` with `$this->id` and similar with password

Comment: 1) How do I handle the url of the external site? Since the url also requires the variables. 2) Does $username:$password have to be within the ""?

Comment: 1) It would be strange to provide them both in the URL and inside the AUTH headers. Please check the documentation of the api 2) well you need to concatenate them with a colon in between. You could also write `$this->id . ':' . $this->key`